# Guardar valores de tabelas em Excel

Tags: php

Tenho ai todo o código necessario mas esta a dar um erro e tem a ver com o `$i`. como posso corrigir?

```
<?php 
include('conetar.php');
$query = "SELECT nome, contacto  FROM utilizadores";
$executar_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$contar = mysqli_num_rows($executar_query);

for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){   
$html[$i] = "";
    $html[$i] .= "<table>";
    $html[$i] .= "<tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Nome</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>contacto</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "</tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "</table>";
}

$i = 1;
while($ret = mysqli_fetch_array($executar_query)){
    $retorno_nome = $ret['nome'];
    $retorno_contacto = $ret['contacto'];
    $html[$i] .= "<table>";
    $html[$i] .= "<tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>".$retorno_nome."</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>".$retorno_contacto."</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "</tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "</table>";
    $i++;
}

$arquivo = 'soudev.xlsx';
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2100 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$arquivo}" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );


for($i=0;$i<=$contar;$i++){  
    echo $html[$i];
}


 ?>
```

IMAGEM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A linha 21, pelo que eu contei, fica aqui: `$html[$i] .= "<table>";`.

Esse erro, acontece porque esse array com aquela chave não foi declarada ainda, então, você está concatenando um array com uma chave que não "existe". Para arruma isso, basta declarar aquele array com a chave antes de concatenar os valores.

```
...
$html[$i] = ""; // aqui está declarado o array com a chave determinada 
$html[$i] .= "<table>";
$html[$i] .= "<tr>";
...
```

Esse é um erro do tipo *notice*, ou seja, seu script provavelmente estava funcionando normalmente. Mas é legal arrumar essas coisinhas. =)

Comment: basta alterar `$html[$i] .= "<table>";` para `$html[$i] = "<table>" em ambas as tags `<table>`

Comment: Sim, também funcionará. Mas acredito que minha resposta está correta. É só reparar na minha explicação.

Comment: Inclusive, no `for` você fez exatamente isso: `$html[$i] = "";`. Eu apenas segui sua linha de raciocínio. Acho que você deveria aprovar minha resposta. Abraço.

Comment: Também pode colocar a minha como uma boa duvida porque assim o `exportar` para `xls` funciona perfeitamente e saberão como usar.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque `$html = [];`, antes do `for`.